# Key Error: 'eth_usd_price_feed' during brownie test

Tags: solidity, ganache, testing, brownie, solidity-0.8.x

```
from brownie import Lottery, accounts, config, network
from web3 import Web3


def test_get_entrance_fee():
    account = accounts[0]
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"],
        {"from": account},
    )
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() > Web3.toWei(0.012, "ether")
    assert lottery.getEntranceFee() < Web3.toWei(0.015, "ether")
```

Comment: Trying to test if my contract is getting the correct entrance fee. Contract compiled without errors. It seems the error is in the test function but i cant find it. 
Brownie config as follows:
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1"
networks:
  eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'

Comment: test summary info:
FAILED tests/test_lottery.py::test_get_entrance_fee - KeyError: 'eth_usd_price_feed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your brownie config file. The networks: branch should look something like this:

```
networks:
  mainnet-fork-dev:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
  development:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
```

i.e. there should be a network name in between `networks` and `eth-usd-price-feed`